# string_view not found when compiling c++17 code with clang in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, string-view

I got the error message:

```
src/HttpRouter.h:28:10: fatal error: 'string_view' file not found
```

when trying to compile a library (uWebSockets) which happened to show the command it called to compile:

```
clang++ -flto -O3 -c -std=c++17 -Isrc -IuSockets/src examples/HelloWorld.cpp
```

I checked /usr/include and `string_view` was only found inside `experimental`

```
john@blam /usr/include $ find . | grep string_view
  ./c++/5/experimental/string_view.tcc
  ./c++/5/experimental/string_view
```

Even after I updated to libstdc++6-dev, it still can't find string_view library which came from the `#include <string_view>` line.

What gives?

Comment: Simply means that ubuntu has not packaged a recent enough version of libstdc++. Look up PPAs if by chance any of them provides a more recent libstdc++. Alternatively, try to install libc++ and pass -stdlib=libc++ to clang.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning the *version* of `clang` you are using as that could be a factor. (Or at least the version of `Ubuntu`)

Comment: You are right, I updated gcc and g++ to version 8 and now it can find string_view just fine. Thanks! I also did upgrade clang first before trying that, but that didn't seem to fix it.